Viewing bitmap without interpolation (with Feh or otherwise)
My preferred image viewer is Feh. When I open a small image with Feh, there is very intrusive interpolation between pixels. I would like to turn this off and just view the raw pixels. How can I do this with Feh? Or will another program be in order?
Edit: I realise the original post was ambiguous. My question is better stated as "how can I view the image zoomed in with an interpolation which preserves the original blockiness?"; e.g., zooming x and y by 2 should render a single blue pixel as a 4-pixel large blue block. This intention was inferred from my OP and I have accepted an answer :)

what do you mean with "raw pixels"? You mean you don't want to zoom in? Any zoom will inherently require interpolation - be it nearest neighbors (the most incorrect of all popular interpolations, from an image theory point of view), linear (still terribly wrong, only excuse is "my 8 bit computer has only 512 kB RAM", and shouldn't exist in 2024.), quadratic approximation to sinc (correct in spirit, suboptimal in execution), spline or other approximations to sinc interpolation…

Interpolation is never required.  While zoomed in, it displays the image inaccurately while making it look better.  At higher resolution, it averages combined pixels, but you can sample pixels without doing that, it just loses information.

@user10489 you are misinterpreting what the word "interpolation" means. Your image (say, 800×800 pixel) only lists pixel values for its original (640000) pixel positions. If you want to view it at a resolution that's not its original size, then you need to interpolate the values of the pixels that don't happen to fall onto the original pixel positions. So,interpolation is inherent; it must happen when you look at an image that's smaller than the pixel surface you put it on. "Averaging" is a "kind-of" correct term for what can happen there,see the methods I listed in my first comment.

I think (not sure, actually) that you want to have something like "put this 800×800 px image on a surface that's 1600×1600 px large, and to do that, please divide each output pixels positiion by 2, then pick the input pixel that's closes to that position". That interpolation method works (it's what "nearest neighbor" means) and gives you "blocky" zooming, i.e., 2×2 sized "pixel blocks".

Things go horribly wrong, however, when you try to put a 700×700 px large image on a 1600×1600 surface. Now, some pixel blocks are 2×2, some are 3×2, some are 2×3, some are 3×3. And you notice that (as human observer) as kind of a "wavy stretchedness with block artifacts". So, that nearest-neighbor/uniform pixel blocks approach can only work if the "zoomed version" is 2×, or 3× or 4×, or any other integer multiple of the original size. Is that a restriction you can live with?

"displays the image inaccurately" is by the way the thing that signal theory people (like me, sorry) will tell you is wrong: it's inaccurate to use nearest neighbor to increase the size of an image, because the original material being depicted in a pixel image does not have the "abrupt" transition between pixels. The opposite is the case! A pixel image is a sampled version, and all photography theory, but also all theory of how to process (photographic and non-photographic) images, how to reproduce them with screens, AR spectacles, projectors including their lenses, scaling algorithms in…

… GPUs and so on, is based on the sampling theorem, which tells us the correct interpolation for a well-produced image is sinc-shaped, not nearest-neighbor. This is probably totally irrelevant, as you want to see the individual pixels, I guess!! But don't throw around words like "inaccurately" if you really mean "not nearest-neighbor".

@MarcusMüller You are wrong about interpolation.  You can direct sample an image when changing resolution.  It's stupid and looks awful and loses info and sometimes distorts the image, but that doesn't mean you can't do it.  Interpolation is not inherent, but it certainly is the best way to do it.

@user10489 sorry, again, you're misinterpreting what "interpolation" means. it doesn't imply "smoothness" or something. It literally just means "finding values for points between the points you're actually given"; what you mean with "directly sampling" is in fact an interpolation method, the nearest neighbor method described above. (I taught this stuff, I work in DSP, you'll have a hard time convincing me that you're the expert in the room.) (unless you mean that when you scale up a 800×800 image to 1600×1600, ¾ of the pixels have undefined values. Then you're not using interpolation)

Interpolation involves finding new values between other values.  If you want to call direct sampling that copies values instead of calculating new ones, I suppose that could be a degenerate form of interpolation, but it seems like a semantic abuse of the term to me.  I don't care if you teach this stuff, maybe you teach it wrong.  Not like you haven't posted other wrong stuff here.  I've been doing image processing for 40+ years.

It's not a degenerate form, it's simply a form of interpolation :) I don't understand how you contradict yourself: in the first sentence, you correctly say "Interpolation involves finding new values between other values", which is exactly right (it not only involves that, it's the finding of new values between other values while making sure that if you happen to look at the positions of the original values in the interpolated data, they are identical to the original values. That's literally the definition of interpolation). That's all there is to it – upsampling by dividing the target…

coordinate down by the scaling factor and using the value of the pixel closes to that divided position is really an appropriate method of interpolation! Nothing abusive about that terminology. It's nice and mathematically consistent, and easy to remember: pixel values on integer positions of original grid, new grid has different (finer-distributed) positions, so you need to figure out what values to put on these positions. That's really an interpolation problem, and every method you'll use to solve it is an interpolation method by definition, as long as it keeps the values for these grid…

…positions that agree between the two grids the same.

And I mean, I didn't come up with this terminology, this is really common image processing terminology, e.g. in the references listed on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest-neighbor_interpolation .

The feh option --force-aliasing turns off the smoothing while zoomed in.  The A key also toggles it.
I notice other image viewers also enable this by default under other names (such as smoothing, interpolation, aliasing, etc.)
